# Is a kernel level thread binded to a process?

Tags: multithreading, process

I know kernel level thread and process are both managed by the operating system. Typically, a thread is created to be within a process. KLT within the process act like a virtual cpu for the user level threads within the process. But my question is, can a KLT change the process it belongs to? Further more, I heard that sometimes a KLT doesn't even need to be associated with a process. How is this even possible? In this case, what is the memory space?

Comment: Can you please clarify what OS you are talking about and ideally provide sources? "KLT within the process act like a virtual cpu for the user level threads within the process. " sounds like you refer to a specific runtime environment (something with green threads) drive this is definitely not how threads behave in many common OS and programs.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - My guess is that the OP has read https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kernel-level-threads-in-operating-system/ or something like that.

Comment: @StephenC That thing is barely legible at times, but I am pretty sure it makes it clear that kernel threads can’t change which  processes they belong to (at least as far in as I daunted to venture).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Hi, I am mainly referring to what is covered in this video https://youtu.be/LGAuT2j5GQA?si=oMQtM_jszcOWZ13V&t=234.

Answer (score 0):

> But my question is, can a KLT change the process it belongs to?

No.  It can't<sup>1</sup>.

I am assuming that KLT is referring to POSIX threads and the like; i.e. threads that operate in user space and are scheduled to different physical cores by the OS kernel.  These are also called Kernel Threads.  Though (confusingly) Kernel Thread is also used (by some people) to refer to OS managed threads that operate in kernel space; e.g. [Kernel Threads and User Threads](https://www.ibm.com/docs/zh/aix/7.1?topic=processes-kernel-threads-user-threads)

Please cite the source of >your< definition / understanding of KLT (Kernel Level Thread).

> Further more, I heard that sometimes a KLT doesn't even need to be associated with a process. How is this even possible? In this case, what is the memory space?

I have not heard this.  Please cite a source for this so that we can try to figure out what is being said / claimed.

---

<sup>1 - A KLT thread interacts with the memory of a process and the other KLT threads belonging to the process.  What is the use-case for moving one to a different process?  What would the semantics be?  What about security, etc?</sup>

---

It should be said that IT terminology related "threads" and "processes", is somewhat fluid.  Different people use the words differently, and the concepts have evolved over time.

For something like this, I would give the terminology in the Wikipedia [Thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) page more credence than some random web tutorial.  Wikipedia pages tend to represent a *consensus* by virtue of the fact that many people contribute to them.  Web tutorial pages are typically the work of a single person whose knowledge on the topic is often shallow.

Comment: Hi Stephen. Indeed what I read was kernel thread doesn't have to be associated with a process, not kernel level threads. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-weight_process. But still, I am unsure what the difference between a kernel thread and a kernel level thread is. Aren't they the same?

Comment: I think we may have found two Wikipedia pages that contradict each other.  My advice would be to read each one independently then relate what the two pages are saying *without assuming that the terminology is consistent*.  Don't get hung up on the (inconsistent) terminology.

Comment: @zhongyuanchen, "kernel thread" has special meaning for Linux kernel developers. It means something different from what you are calling "kernel _level_ thread." A Linux kernel thread is not associated with any process. It only ever executes kernel code, and only ever accesses kernel-space variables. A Linux kernel thread exists only to serve the kernel's needs, and there is no reason why "user space" code ever needs to be aware of it (except for user space programs like `ps` whose job is to reveal system state.)